# Windows 8: multiple monitors not found on restart

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a laptop with Windows 8 and a 22" monitor that I use simultaneously. If I start up, then connect the monitor via HDMI (using Intel HD3000 graphics) I can set up an extened desktop no problem. However when I next turn on the computer, leaving the cable plugged in, my laptop display stays blank. The Intel control panel and Windows control panel both agree that it's there, and I can drag windows there, but it stoically refuses to turn on.

Has anyone else had this, and/or know what to do about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the monitor on another system.  Try a different HDMI monitor.

Comment: I have had (and still have) this exact same issue on an HP laptop I have at home. The drivers don't seem to toggle output to the second screen until the 'plug in' event fires

Comment: In regards to my previous comment I think it is also good to clarify that the laptop I have is using Windows 7 so I think this is more related to the Intel HD Graphics drivers

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your divers are out of date. You need to run Windows Updates, and install them. Then get the latest driver from Intel for your graphics card. Reboot your machine with out the monitor plugged in. Once you have logged in to your account, pug in your monitor. Use the windows key + p to open your projecting options. Select extend desktop, then select

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I did everything you said, but it didn't entirely work. My laptop screen was blank (but on) on boot. I put it sleep and woke it up and it was fine, but I don't want to have to do this every time I boot!

Comment: Have you updated your BIOS? If not I would do that.